# Excel: How to copy formula across cells that is based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have used a formula
=SUM(A3:A16)*0.7 + SUM(B3:B16)*0.25 + SUM(C3:C16)*0.05

when I drag this formula across column I want the next column to be

=SUM(D3:D16)*0.7 + SUM(E3:E16)*0.25 + SUM(F3:F16)*0.05

Instead it is showing:
=SUM(B3:B16)*0.7 + SUM(C3:C16)*0.25 + SUM(D3:D16)*0.05

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to combine the `SUMPRODUCT` and `INDEX` functions in an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($A$1:$ZZ$16,N(IF(1,ROW($A$1:$A$16))),N(IF(1,COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)+3*(COLUMN()-1))))*{0.7;0.25;0.05})
```

Adjust range `$A$1:$ZZ$16` as you need.

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Line 12 contains your formula.

Answer (score 0):

As the ranges are contiguous, you could also do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($A$3:$I$16,1,(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A:$A))*3+1):
INDEX($A$3:$I$16,ROWS($A$3:$I$16),(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A:$A))*3+3)*{0.7,0.25,0.05})
```

[image]